# angular.isNumber not working

Tags: angularjs

**In my route controller I have the following code:**

```
console.log('quantaryNav:' + $routeParams.quantaryNav);

// quantaryNav
if ($routeParams.quantaryNav!= "" && $routeParams.quantaryNav!= undefined) {
    console.log('result: ' + angular.isNumber($routeParams.quantaryNav ));
}
```

**Console logs:**

```
quantaryNav :12 
result :false
```

Is there a way to determine if a route param is a number in the controller?

Post Script:
  This works

```
     console.log('raw: ' + angular.isNumber(12));

     raw: true
```

But obviously I cannot hard code the value.

**Thanks to mpm this works:**

```
  console.log('quantaryNav!!: ' + angular.isNumber(+($routeParams.quantaryNav)));

    quantaryNav!!: true
    quantaryNav :12
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
angular.isNumber(+($routeParams.quantaryNav))
```

try that

$routeParams.quantaryNav might come up as a string so you need to "cast" it anyway if your app        requires a number.

Comment: Won't this return true every time then?  angular.isNumber(+("asdf")) returns true.

Comment: kukabuka is right.  When you cast the value with angular.isNumber everything comes back as true.  I'm not sure how to use angular.isNumber properly but the answer for me was to use isFinite.  This works as I need it to without casting.  ex) isFinite($routeParams.quantaryNav)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to happen because the value is actually a string which would imply casting the value to a number. However when you cast the value before using with angular.isNumber all values will return true because angular.isNumber includes the "special" numbers NaN, +Infinity and -Infinity which is what non-numeric values cast to. The answer for me was to use isFinite. This works as I need it to without casting.

```
isFinite($routeParams.quantaryNav)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite